# Change font tracking dynamically Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, swift3

I am using `SF UI Display` font everywhere in the project. In accordance with the [Apple human interface guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/) font spacing should change dynamically depending on changes of the size. For example:

- Title-1 size: 28pt spacing: **13pt**
- Title-2 size: 22pt spacing: **16pt**
- Title-3 size: 20pt spacing: **19pt**

I declare fonts like this in code:

```
extension UIFont {
    class func CustomFont(name: String, size: CGFloat) -> UIFont? {
        return UIFont(name: name, size: size)
    }
}
```

Example of different font sizes with the same spacing:

[image]
[image]`
[image]

But as I see now, spacing for all fonts in my project is the same. Is it possible to fix it in one place for the whole project?

Comment: any screenshot? and how you change fonts? code interface builder?

Comment: @Lu_ I've changed the description

Comment: try adding .sizeToFit() to your label if you are changing font from code

Comment: @Lu_ I'd already use `sizeToFit()`, so the result you can see on the pictures is with this method. Unfortunately is doesn't help.